# MySQL. How to combine or match specifics rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, sql-null

First, the title is not very clear. With this example I would like to know if there is a solution with SQL code or if it has to be worked in the other side with C#, Java, PHP, etc.

The principle is this:

1. There is a table of ***Inputs***, like this:

```
    ID  Name   Amount
    1   AA     10   
    2   BB     9
    3   CC     8
    4   DD     1
    5   ZZ     2
```

2. And there is a table of ***Outputs***:

```
    ID  Name   Fouls   
    1   BB     4
    2   ZZ     1
```

3. What I'm trying to get is a subtraction of the quantities, based on each matching column, hoping to get the following:

```
    Name   Diff
    AA     10   
    BB     5
    CC     8
    DD     1
    ZZ     1
```

Can it be done directly with SQL?

Comment: will there be outputs with no corresponding inputs?

Comment: @ysth Yeah, but in the real scope of this example, the ***Inputs*** are the primordial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `left join`:

```
select i.name, i.amount - coalesce(o.fouls, 0) diff
from inputs i
left join outputs o on o.name = i.name
```

Comment: My fault was not to use COALESCE, without it it always returned NULL. Thanks !!

Comment: @EveRegalado always show what you've tried; it makes it a lot easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `left join` and arithmetic:

```
select i.id, i.name, i.amount - coalesce(o.fouls, 0)
from inputs i left join
     outputs o
     using (id)
```

Comment: My fault was not to use COALESCE, Thanks !!